# How to return a class using the constructor in java?

Tags: java

How to return this `Customer` class so i can use this class in another class.

If i use `static` instead of `void` then i am unable to call customer Transaction from the constructor.

I tried writing new keyword but it did not work but this is returning a class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Customer  {
        private String name;
        private ArrayList<Double> customerTranscation;

    public Customer(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.customerTranscation = new ArrayList<Double>();
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public ArrayList<Double> getCustomerTranscation() {
        return customerTranscation;
    }

    public void newCustomerTran(String name,double amount){
        this.customerTranscation.add(amount);
         this.name = name;

    }
}
```

How can I return `Customer` class so I can use this in another class?

Comment: `new Customer("name")`?

Comment: The only `void` I see in your program is `newCustomerTran`. What is it supposed to do? What kind of customer object do you want to return? An existing one? A new one?

Comment: public void newCustomerTran(String name,double amount){
        this.customerTranscation.add(amount);
         this.name = name;

    }

Comment: public void newCustomerTran(String name,double amount){
        this.customerTranscation.add(amount);
         this.name = name;

    } i want to make this public static Customer new CustomerTran(String name, double amount){this.customerTranscation.add(amount);  this.name = name;   return new Customer;}

Comment: *"If i use static instead of void"* This is not an *'instead'* scenario! `void` is declaring the **return type**, just as `ArrayList<Double>` and `String` are for your other methods.  `static` vs non-static (i.e. absence of the `static` keyword) is whether the method exists at the instance or class level.

Answer (score 1):

In you second class, You got to create the object of the customer class first . 
Like `Customer c=new Customer(“abc”);`

This is going to initialise the CustomerTransaction List.

Then call `c.newCustomerTrans(“name”)`.which will invoke the newCustomeTrans method from your second class.

If you want an customer object to be returned . Do .!

```
public Customer newCustomerTrans(String name ,double amount){
//create a new object p of Customer using new
//set name to p
//initialise and set customer trans arraylist to p
// return p 
}
```

This way you can use Customer class details from your second class..